# mongodb: Globally replace all references to one ObjectID with another?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

So I have a MongoDB database with millions of records in a few collections. Here's a (greatly simplified) example of some records...

Collection A documents look like:

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectID(....)
  name: "Hubert Humphrey"
}
```

Collection B documents look like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectID(....)
  ReferenceSummary: [
    { 
      person: ObjectID(<some-ID-from-Collection-A>)
      count: 312
    },
    { 
      person: ObjectID(<some-other-ID-from-Collection-A>)
      count: 42
    },
    ...
  ], 
  TopPeople: [ ObjectID(<another-ID-from-Collection-A>), ObjectID(<yet-another-ID-from-Collection-A>), ...]
}
```

Now here's the problem. We realized we have a few duplicates (only 3 or 4) in Collection A. And they're each referenced hundreds of thousands of times in Collection B.

However, there are no instances where a given Collection B document references two different Collection A documents which are duplicates of each other.

So, what I need to do to fix this is: For each pair of duplicates in Collection A, with `_id`'s `ObjectId(X)` and `ObjectId(Y)`, replace all occurrences of `ObjectId(Y)` with `ObjectId(X)` for all documents in Collection B.

If I was dealing with raw JSON files, I'd just do a string substitution and be done with it.

Is there a simple way to do this in the mongo shell, just using one command for each of the Collection A duplicates?

Comment: I assume that person is a duplicate - do you have a way to select duplicates (this is by id field or other metadata?)

Comment: It's only a few specific duplicates, caused by manual entry errors. An easy way to replace all references to one of them at a time would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The siplest way to get this job done is use `forEach` loop

```
var ids = [id1, id2, ...., idN];
var idsToReplace = [id1TR, id2TR, ...., IdNTR];
var aLenght = ids.lenght;

for (var i = o; i < aLenght; i++) {
    db.collectionA.find({
        _id : ids[i]
    }).forEach(function (doc) {
        doc.fieldA = idsToReplace[i];
        // if we habve an array entry we need to iterate thru it
        var arrayXLenght = doc.arrayX.lenght;
        for (var j = 0; j < arrayXLenght; j++) {
            if (doc.arrayX[j].field === ids[i]) {
                doc.arrayX[j].field = idsToReplace[i];
            }
        }

        prinjson(doc); //verify changes
        //doc.save() //uncoment when you wil be assured that changes are ok
    })

    // same thing with other collection
}
```

Comment: OK; was hoping there was a simple command that would just replace every single instance, but it sounds like I do need to loop through manually.